# Riemann mapping theorem - Personal project

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, spectral-theory

I would like to work on the Riemann mapping theorem this summer. Does anyone could give me some good references linked to this objective. For your information, I now currently finishing a degree in pure mathematics.

Comment: What is BAC??...

Comment: For your information, I now currently finishing a degree in pure mathematics.

Comment: Try either Ahlfors' or Conway's complex analysis books. I like them both. Conway has a nice section in his second book where he proves generalizations of Riemann mapping for certain non-simply connected domains.